# PHP Database: value not inserting in table

Tags: php, mysql

**insert.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); mysql_select_db("basic");
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$twait=$_POST['twait'];
$cprice=$_POST['cprice'];
$dprice=$_POST['dprice'];
$order= "INSERT INTO calculator
        (name,total_wt,crt_price,dollar_rate) VALUES
        ('$name','$twait','$cprice','$dprice')";

$result = mysql_query('$order');
echo "Done";
?>
```

**HTML page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JN DIAMONDS</title>
</head>
<body>
<form align="center" method="POST" action="insert.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Info</legend><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="twait" placeholder="Total Rough Weight"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="cprice" placeholder="1 Carat Price"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="dprice" placeholder="Dollar Rate"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit"><br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi John and welcome to SO (StackOverflow). I see you have just joined us. We strive to be a wonderful community and provide people with solutions to their coding problems as best we can. There are some basic fundamentals to [asking a good question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consequently getting more experienced users to help you. In addition, most of us would like to see that you have put some effort into solving your problem. Show us what you've tried and what the results were. Again, welcome to SO!

Comment: Remove quotes form  `$result = mysql_query($order);` And stop using mysql it is deprecated instead use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: If you are not going to use `mysqli or PDO` with bound parameters, which is a bad idea not to, at least don't directly put variable unsanitized into the sql

Comment: Do yourself a favor - **stop using mysql_**. `mysql_` has been [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Using `mysql_` leaves you wide open to [sql injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Soon your code will stop functioning completely and you'll be back asking a [question like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/). Start learning [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). When your host upgrades to PHP 7, you will be so happy you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$order` is a variable containing your mysql string. 
When you put `$order` in quotes, then you are not sending `$order` into the mysql string, you are actually trying to execute the query `'$order'` which is not a valid mysql query.

Simply remove the quotes.

`$result = mysql_query($order);`

Comment: No problem. Please however take note of various comments suggesting that you move away from using `mysql` directly and using `pdo`. Mysql extension is deprecated. I recommend you also take a look at @VolkerK answer.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error in your code has already been pointed out.
The mysql_* extension is [deprecated and will be removed in the upcoming version 7 of php](http://docs.php.net/intro.mysql); choose another api to connect to your MySQL server, e.g. [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo). Using [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) will take care of the worst [sql injections](http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection) as well.

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['twait'], $_POST['cprice'], $_POST['dprice']) ) {
    trigger_error('missing POST parameter in '.var_export($_POST, true), E_USER_WARNING);
    echo '<html><head><title>...</title><body><h1>missing POST parameter</h1></body></html>';
}
else {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basic;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        INSERT INTO
            calculator
            (name,total_wt,crt_price,dollar_rate)
        VALUES
            (:fname,:twait,:cprice,:dprice)
    ');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
        'twait'=>$_POST['twait'],
        'cprice'=>$_POST['cprice'],
        'dprice'=>$_POST['dprice']
    ));
    echo "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this code

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); mysql_select_db("basic");
    $name=$_POST['fname']; 
    $twait=$_POST['twait'];
    $cprice=$_POST['cprice']; 
    $dprice=$_POST['dprice'];
    $order= "INSERT INTO calculator
            (name,total_wt,crt_price,dollar_rate) VALUES
            ('$name','$twait','$cprice','$dprice')";
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    echo "Done";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead of mysql.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'basic');
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$twait=$_POST['twait'];
$cprice=$_POST['cprice'];
$dprice=$_POST['dprice'];
$order= "INSERT INTO `calculator` (name,total_wt,crt_price,dollar_rate) 
VALUES ('".$name."','".$twait."','".$cprice."','".$dprice."')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$order);
echo "Done";
```

Comment: Solving an unrelated problem. Also, bug still in your code. Thumbs down.

Comment: You fixed it yourself. `$result = mysqli_query($order);` was `$result = mysqli_query('$order');`

Comment: Using mysqli just to ignore pepared statements is not an improvement